# How can I have this program add the user input into my linked list?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestClass {
static String name;
static String gender;
static String hairColor;

TestClass(String name, String gender, String hairColor){
    this.name=name;
    this.gender=gender;
    this.hairColor=hairColor;

}
public static void main (String[]args) {
    TestClass info = new TestClass(name, gender, hairColor);
    LinkedList<TestClass> linky = new LinkedList<TestClass>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter name ");
    name=input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter gender ");
    gender=input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter hair color ");
    hairColor=input.nextLine(); 

    }

}
```

I want to add user input into the linked list but I can't figure out how to. I have tried to use `linky.add(name);` but that gives an error. How can I add input into the linked list?

Comment: take a look of the type of linked list linky is, it looks like you need to add a new instance of your TestClass not a String

Comment: Also name, gender and hairColor shouldn't be static, it will help you in the long run

Comment: `TestClass` objects contain no data!  All data members are `static`.  While you can add multiple `TestClass` objects to the linked list, the objects are identical (ignoring reference identity).

Comment: You are using constructor to change static variables which defeats the purpose of static, you want to add object of type String into a LinkedList that accepts objects of type TestClass.

Comment: I tried to make them non-static variables but then when I did, I got errors in my main method that say `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field` on my lines that assign the user's input to the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestClass {
    // These should (most likely) not be static
    // Read up on what 'static' means
    String name;
    String gender;
    String hairColor;

    TestClass(String name, String gender, String hairColor){
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.hairColor = hairColor;
    }

    public static void main (String[]args) {
        LinkedList<TestClass> linky = new LinkedList<TestClass>();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter name ");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter gender ");
        String gender = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter hair color ");
        String hairColor = input.nextLine();

        TestClass info = new TestClass(name, gender, hairColor);

        linky.add(info);
    }
}
```

Since linky is a `LinkedList<TestClass>` with generic type `TestClass` it can only hold objects of type `TestClass` so when you try to `linky.add(name)` it wont work

To print out the contents of the list you will need to iterate through the list and print each element, if the list contained `String`s or something with an Overridden `toString` method, then you could simply call:

```
for(String str : linky){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

**BUT** this will not work because `linky` contains `TestClass`es. Therefor you could do this (but you should probably define `get`er methods for the fields of TestClass):

```
for(TestClass testClass : linky){
    System.out.println("Name: " + testClass.name);
    System.out.println("Gender: " + testClass.gender);
    System.out.println("Hair Color: " + testClass.hairColor);
}
```

OR in `TestClass` you could override the `toString` method inherited from its superclass `Object`

```
// In TestClass
@Override
public String toString(){
    // Format this however you like
    return "Name :" + this.name + "; Gender: " + this.gender + "; Hair Color: " + this.hairColor;
}
```

Then all you would need to do is this:

```
for(TestClass testClass : linky){
    // println(testClass) calls testClass.toString()
    // giving you the formatted data from TestClass
    System.out.println(testClass);
}
```

Comment: How can I print the list? I tried to do `System.out.println(linky.toString());` but that outputs `[TestClass@55f96302]`I know I need to use `toString()` but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @liquidOfficer see edits for your answer. For additional info look up overriding, and also iterating through collections.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to store all the user inputs in the `TestClass` object and then add that object to your `LinkedList`

After taking inputs from user, pass all the variables that contain user input values in to `TestClass` constructor

```
TestClass test = new TestClass(name, gender, hairColor);
```

then store `test` object in your `LinkedList`

```
linky.add(test);
```

**Important Note:**

Data member variables of class `TestClass` should not be `static` if you want to store multiple instances of `TestClass` each having its own data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add new instance of `TestClass` to `LinkedList` like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<TestClass> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter name ");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter gender ");
    String gender = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter hair color ");
    String hairColor = input.nextLine(); 

    list.add(new TestClass(name, gender, hairColor));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList<TestClass> linky = new LinkedList<TestClass>();
```

You need to add your instance of `TestClass`

Answer (score 0):

just change it :

```
LinkedList<String> linky = new LinkedList<String>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter name ");
    name=input.nextLine();
    linky.add(0, name);
    System.out.println("Enter gender ");
    gender=input.nextLine();
    linky.add(1, gender);
    System.out.println("Enter hair color ");
    hairColor=input.nextLine(); 
linky.add(2, hairColor);
```